# Check burned Ubuntu CD

Tags: installation, cd, md5sum

My OS is Ubuntu 10.10. I have burned Ubuntu 11.04 into a CD. Now I tried to check the CD following https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#Check%20the%20CD, as following:

```
$ ls -l
-rwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev 718583808 2011-05-19 10:26 ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso

$ dd if=/dev/cdrom bs=1 count=718583808 | md5sum
dd: reading `/dev/cdrom': Input/output error
718581760+0 records in
718581760+0 records out
718581760 bytes (719 MB) copied5f0528a1b0a834bcf6d25f0b52d97736  -
, 3918.18 s, 183 kB/s
```

My questions are:

1. I found my CD appears as
   /media/Ubuntu 11.04 i386, why not
   verify it, but to verify /dev/cdrom?
2. why did I get "dd: reading
   `/dev/cdrom': Input/output error",
   and only 718581760 out of 718583808
   bytes are processed?
3. How shall I check the CD then?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 6):

Just boot the CD and from the menu run *Check disc for defects*:

[image]

If everything's ok, you should get the message *Check finished: no errors found*.