# Any way to check dvd before i install?

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check the integrity of a downloaded Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd)

I am running the live 12.04 desktop iso. Its working fine but i've had my share of bad installs and would like to check if all the files are good before i install.  How would I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check the integrity of a downloaded Ubuntu CD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-downloaded-ubuntu-cd) or [Check burned Ubuntu CD](http://askubuntu.com/questions/45736/check-burned-ubuntu-cd)

Answer (score 0):

Do a checksum on the iso. Here's how to do it:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM